# Are two touch event listeners on one object in corona sdk possible?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am programming a game where if you press the screen(a massive transparent button) then a moving ball stops. I also want to add the possibility for a player to swipe the screen and get a prize. I want the swipe not to interfere with the touch and not affect the moving object. Is this possible?

```
local function moveBall()
 transition.to( ball, {time = 5000, x = 160,y = 240} )
end

local function stop()
  tranisition.pause()
end


local ball = display.newCircle(0,0,50)

local rectangle = display.newRect(100,200,1000,1000) 
      rectangle:setFillColor(1,1,1,0.2)  
      rectangle:addEventListener("tap",stop)


moveBall()
```

Comment: something makes me believe you haven't read this: https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/index.html

Comment: I did, but I can't really understand it that well. Could you please help?

Comment: and what is it you didn't understand? I find it very simple so I have problems to figure out where you need help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep your code and just add a Runtime listener for touch events and inside that listener you can add a code to identify if the touch made by the user is a swipe.

There are several resources that you can look to find how to identify if a touch is a swipe. One of them is [here](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2014/09/16/tutorial-swiping-an-object-to-fixed-points/)